# How can I debug and see what gets stored over time into the FIFO queue of inter-thread communication plugin?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, jmeter, performance-testing, ibm-mq

I have the following JMeter context:

In one Concurrency Thread Group 1, I have a JSR223 Sampler which sends request messages to an MQ queue1 and always gets the JMSMessageID and an epochTimestamp (derived from JMS_IBM_PutDate + JMS_IBM_PutTime) and puts them into one variable. Underneath this Sampler is an Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor element which gets the data from this variable and puts it into a FIFO QUEUE.

In another Concurrency Thread Group 2,  I have another JSR223 Sampler with code to get the response messages for all the messages sent on MQ queue 1 from an MQ queue2.
To do this, (and be able to calculate the response time fore each message) before the JSR223 Sampler executes, I use the Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor element which gets a message ID and a timestamp from the FIFO queue (60 seconds timeout) and passes it over to a variable with which the JSR223 Sampler can work to calculate the request-response time for each message.

I want to stress-test the system, which is why I am gradually dynamically increasing the Requests per second at every 1 minute (for script testing purposes) in both thread groups, like so:
[image]
I use the `tstFeedback` function of Concurrency Thread Group for this:

```
${__tstFeedback(ThroughputShapingTimerIn,1,1000,10)}
```

My problem is this:

When I gradually increase the desired TPS load, during the first 4 target TPS steps, the Consumer threads keep up (synchronized) with the Producer threads, but as the time passes and load increases, the consumer threads seem to be taking more time to find and consume the messages. It's as though the load of the consumer treads is no longer able to keep up with the load of the producer threads, despite both thread groups having the same load pattern. This eventually causes the queue2 which is keeping the response messages to get full. Here is a visual representation of what I mean:
[image]
The Consumer samples end up being much less than the producer samples. My expectation is that they should be more or less equal...
[image]

I need to understand how I can go about to debug this script and isolate the cause:

- I think that something happens at the inter-thread synchronization level because sometimes I am getting null values from the FIFO queue into the consumer threads - I need to understand what gets put into that FIFO queue and what gets taken off of that FIFO queue.
  How can I print what is present in the FIFO list at each iteration?
- Does anyone have any suggestions for what could be the cause of this behavior and how to mitigate it?

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), you have at least 865 errors there so I strongly doubt your Groovy scripts are doing what they're supposed to be doing

   [image]
2. [Don't run your test in GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode), it's only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to execution you should be using command-line non-GUI mode
3. When you call `__fifoPop()` you can save the value into a JMeter Variable like `${__fifoPop(queue-name,some-variable)}`, the variable can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler). The size of the queue can be checked using `__fifoSize()` function

   [image]

   Alternatively my expectation is that such a Groovy expert as you shouldn't have any problems printing queue items in Groovy code:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I don't use the functions to put and get messages from the FIFO queue - I use the "out-of-the-box" test elements Inter-Thread Communication postprocessor and preprocessor. Are you saying that the only option is to change the approach to use the functions of the Inter-Thread Communication plugin  in a JSR223 sampler, if I want to print elements from inside the queue?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use

Comment: Here is a summary of the log errors:
**1.** I have the first error that the consumer got a null object from the outbound queue
**2.** Then I have only one error like this: 
`javax.script.ScriptException: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'OUTPUT'.
... stacktrace blabla...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '3013' ('').`

Comment: **3.** Then as far as I can tell most of the errors are like this:
`com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedResourceAllocationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue
... stacktrace blabla...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2017' ('MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE')`

All the errors are visible only on the client side.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I have very low groovy knowledge. The code which you wrote to print elements from the FIFO queue does not work for me. 
As per your screenshot I wrote this code:
`<g.apc.jmeter.modifiers.FifoMap.getInstance()['foo'].eachWithIndex { entry, index -> log.info ('Entry # ' + index + ': ' + entry)}`
I am getting this error in the Sampler Response message:
`Script4526.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: 'g' @ line 1, column 2.
   <g.apc.jmeter.modifiers.FifoMap.getInstance()['inbound_queue_messages'].eachWithIndex { entry, index -> log.info ('Entry # ' + index + ': ' + entry)}
    ^`

Comment: The screenshot is for illustrative purposes, you're supposed to know what you're doing and get the idea instead of copying and pasting the code from the Internet. In particular this case you forgot to copy and paste the first letter `k`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works now. I try my best to learn every day... I got the idea of what I need to do, but I just don't know how to do it. I hope someday I'll be able to help people the same way you do. Know that I am very grateful for your help.